# Splitting a users name

Tags: vb6, split

Hey all, i am trying to split a users name but i am having problems with doing so. Below is my version if the user name has a "go by" name in brackets ():

```
theName = "Gates, Bill W. (Bill)"
hasBracket = False

If InStr(theName, "(") <> 0 Then
    hasBracket = True
End If

If hasBracket = True Then
    bracketPos = InStr(theName, ",")

    lName = StrConv(Trim(Left(theName, bracketPos - 1)), vbProperCase)

    theName = Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos + 2))
    bracketPos = InStr(theName, " ")

    fName = StrConv(Trim(Left(theName, bracketPos - 1)), vbProperCase)

    theName = Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos))

    If Trim(Left(theName, 1)) <> "(" Then
        mName = StrConv(Replace(Trim(Left(theName, 1)), ".", ""), vbProperCase)
    Else
        mName = ""
    End If

    bracketPos = InStr(theName, "(")

    bName = StrConv(Replace(Replace(Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos)), "(", ""), ")", ""), vbProperCase)
Else
    ...
End If
```

That part works just fine as long as it has the "()" in the user name. Now going to the ELSE part where the "()" are not used is somewhat of a challenge for me it seems. Problem being is that the user name can be formatted as such:

```
Gates, Bill W.
Gates, Bill
```

Maybe i am just over thinking it but i can not seem to check if it has a middle name or not using the code from above for the ELSE section:

```
ELSE
    bracketPos = InStr(theName, ",")

    lName = StrConv(Trim(Left(theName, bracketPos - 1)), vbProperCase)

    theName = Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos + 2))
    bracketPos = InStr(theName, " ")

    If bracketPos <> 0 Then
        fName = StrConv(Trim(Left(theName, bracketPos - 1)), vbProperCase)
    End If

    theName = Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos))

    If Trim(Left(theName, 1)) <> "(" Then
        mName = StrConv(Replace(Trim(Left(theName, 1)), ".", ""), vbProperCase)
    Else
        mName = ""
    End If

    MsgBox lName & " " & fName & " " & mName
END IF
```

The code above works just fine if the user name is "Gates, Bill W." but not if its "Gates, Bill". What can i do in order to check to see if it has a middle name because currently, if it does not, then i get an error on line:

```
theName = Trim(Mid(theName, bracketPos))
```

Any help would be great, thanks! :o)

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why i didnt think of this before! Solved! :o)

```
Dim arryTmp() As String
Dim theName As String
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim mName As String
Dim bName As String

theName = "Gates, Bill W."
arryTmp = Split(theName, " ")

If InStr(theName, "(") <> 0 Then
    If UBound(arryTmp) = 3 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase)
        mName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(2)), vbProperCase), ".", "")
        bName = Replace(Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(3)), vbProperCase), ")", ""), "(", "")
    ElseIf UBound(arryTmp) = 2 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase)
        mName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(2)), vbProperCase), ".", "")
    ElseIf UBound(arryTmp) = 1 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(arryTmp) = 3 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase) & " " & StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(2)), vbProperCase)
        mName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(3)), vbProperCase), ".", "")
    ElseIf UBound(arryTmp) = 2 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase)
        mName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(2)), vbProperCase), ".", "")
    ElseIf UBound(arryTmp) = 1 Then
        lName = Replace(StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(0)), vbProperCase), ",", "")
        fName = StrConv(Trim(arryTmp(1)), vbProperCase)
    End If
End If

MsgBox lName & " " & fName & " " & mName & " " & bName

MsgBox lName & " " & fName & " " & mName & " " & bName
```

Comment: If you are splitting on " " you don't need the `Trim`s anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure off the top of my head, but this is where writing a series of tests would be helpful.

I'm not sure if there is any kind of TDD software for VB6 but you can easily make something to help you write this "UserNameSplit" function

At the end of your method, have it print out, your name parts, firstname, lastname,  etc

Then write a TestMethod that will call UserNameSplit with something simple "Bill Gates"
Call it, and when the printed output is correct, add another call to UserNameSplit with something more complicated "Gates, Bill"

Keep adding calls, incrementally.  Ensuring you don't break anything prior when adding new features to your UserNameSplit method.  As soon as one of the outputs is incorrect, backup to a working state, and try again.

Also, looking at your code you need to stop re-using variables.  If it's named "bracketPos" it should never contain the position of a comma, or space.  It makes the code very hard to read and follow, and is probably the reason this method is confusing and your bug hard to find.